# Run a jar file as a linux service

Tags: linux, service, jar

I want to know how i can run a .jar file as a linux service. I am new to linux, so most of the online resources were not of much help.. Any input regarding this will be helpful..

Comment: What do you mean by run as Linux service? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @ manil : your question is exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311268/tool-for-creating-a-java-daemon-service-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to run jar.  You can always run a java program as background task.

In bash

```
$nohup <path to java>  -classpath <classpath> classname  &
```

It looks like [Java service wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/example.html)  is a solution that could fit your case.

Comment: Java service wrapper is a paid service..is there a free alternative to this??

Comment: I want to run the jar as a service so that it gets started on system start up an d closes at system shut down. I would prefer running it as a service as i have complete control over the application.

Comment: @ manil did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311268/tool-for-creating-a-java-daemon-service-on-linux ; Offtopic.