# How to create Java daemon in Centos

Tags: java, daemon

I made a research how to create Java daemon which can run on Centos. I found that there is a two ways:

1. Using C code to start the daemon [example](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311268/tool-for-creating-a-java-daemon-service-on-linux).
2. Pure java daemon with init scripts [example](http://barelyenough.org/blog/2005/03/java-daemon/).

Which one to choose. I prefer the pure Java solution. Would you share some experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep things as simple as possible. I would use the pure java start from shell script approach. Or you can start the process using cron, if you want to run the process as a user.

Comment: +1 for "pure java start from shell script approach", another [script example](https://github.com/alexkasko/java-daemon)