# Linux Launch java program on startup (EC2 instance)

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

my server program needs to be launched on the startup of an EC2 instance. At the minute im just launching it from my SSH with the following commands:

```
 java -jar ~/DocumentManager/DocumentServer-0.2.jar
```

I tried adding this to the .bashrc and /etc/rc.local files but they only seem to work when i ssh in.

Anyone know how to make it so an instance of my application is launched when the computer boots?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Perhaps this helps:[Tool for creating a Java daemon service on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1311268/697630)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you can create a script `java_server_launch.sh` like this:

```
 #! /usr/bin/sh

    PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
    JAVA=/usr/bin/java
    MY_SERVER=/home/your_username/DocumentManager/DocumentServer-0.2.jar
    USER=your_username
    /bin/su - $USER -c "$JAVA -jar $MY_SERVER &"
```

Put your script under /etc/init.d directory, and then use the command:

```
update-rc.d java_server_launch.sh defaults
```

more on *update-rc.d* command by using `man update-rc.d`.

Hope this help.

Regards.

Comment: Hi, I tried that and its not working. I ssh'd in and looked at the processes running and its not there. Do i need to put in a start script somewhere?

Comment: @BenFlowers : hello, yes under /etc/init.d directory

Comment: Okay so basically i created the java_server_launch.sh file and then ran the commands you said. Is there anything else i need to do? (still not working) thanks for your help btw

Comment: @BenFlowers : I edited my post, by the way you can take a look at /etc/init.d/skeleton file to see how you can use it to meet your need.

Comment: still not working, its close i can tell!! so my jar file is located at ~/DocumentManager/DocumentServer-0.2.jar and i am sshing in as ubuntu@(amazoninstance).                                             im storing my script.sh file in /etc/init.d and it looks like this:

#! /usr/bin/sh

    PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
    JAVA=/usr/bin/java
    MY_SERVER=~/DocumentManager/DocumentServer-0.2.jar
    USER=ubuntu
    /bin/su - $USER -c "$JAVA -jar $MY_SERVER &"


and running
update-rc.d script.sh defaults

any clue what im doing wrong?

Comment: FIXED IT!! just needed to chmod +x the script file D'OH!

Comment: never underestimate the stupidity of someone who has been trying to fix a small problem for 3 hours! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Add ampersand(symbol '&') at the end of the command.
For example, in your case, `java -jar ~/DocumentManager/DocumentServer-0.2.jar &`

Old question, but my answer might be helpful for people who look in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run your program as a service which automatically run on ec2 container reboot. Below link worked for me:

https://medium.com/@lizlieholleza/run-your-java-application-as-a-service-in-an-ec2-instance-amazon-linux-d7c7b4c0b2f4