# Jar not running

Tags: java, jar, startup

So I created a script the the following commands

```
#! /usr/bin/sh

    PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
    JAVA=/usr/bin/java
    MY_SERVER=/home/user/Desktop/Hello.jar
    USER=user
    /bin/su - $USER -c "$JAVA -jar $MY_SERVER &"
```

And I saved it in

```
etc/init.d/
```

And then ran the following command in terminal

```
sudo update-rc.d java_server_launch.sh defaults
```

I have a program located at

```
/home/user/Desktop/
```

And it is called **Hello.jar** and it works fine when I run it. When I restart my computer for some reason the program (Hello.jar) does not execute. What am I doing wrong?

I'm doing exactly what the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809191/linux-launch-java-program-on-startup-ec2-instance) says.

Comment: Why the dollar sign before hello?

Comment: Dollar sign was removed but still doesn't work. And yes Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `Hello.jar` with `$MY_SERVER` in the last line of your bash script. That's because your current working directory isn't `/home/user/Desktop`

Edit: Try replacing the last line of code with this:

```
/bin/su $USER -c "$JAVA -jar $MY_SERVER &"
```

Comment: I've updated my code, yet when I restart the program doesn't run on startup.

Answer (score 0):

if you're running on Ubuntu you should check out [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html)

see how simple it is to run jar https://stackoverflow.com/a/12102542/41576

Comment: I'd rather have a solution that doesn't involve installing other programs and one that will work on other Linux distributions as I don't only use Ubuntu.