# How to start .jar file on AWS instance startup as ec2-user?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

It is no problem to start an .jar file with java -jar my-jar-file.jar on startup. I only have to put the command in the rc.locale and it works. 
But how can I start my .jar file as ec2-user on startup? Is that possible?

Comment: Check the usage of "user data" in ec2, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I checked it out an tried it with this simple script: `#!/bin/bash
java -jar /home/ec2-user/quote-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`
Am I missing something? Of course there is a break between bash and java

Comment: nevermind...i solved the problem in a different way: adapted the rc.local file with the command `su ec2-user -c 'java -jar path'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux Launch java program on startup (EC2 instance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809191/linux-launch-java-program-on-startup-ec2-instance)