# How to get password from console when java application is invoked using nohup

Tags: java, console, inputstream, nohup

I want to start a sever application, written in java, after verifying the users authorization to start the server app. So, I tried implementing it using `System.console()`. The problem is my server app is started using `nohup`. So, `System.console()` always returns null...

How can I have console based username and password inputs in a JVM started with nohup.

Comment: may help - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2570/execute-nohup-command-with-input. IMHo, you should re-consider the design/requirement.

Comment: how are you verifying the user name/password? what interface are they typing in their name/password?

Comment: linux/unix/aix terminal

Comment: You may want use `nohup` ( or some other mechanism for that matter ), only after you have completed the authorization. A shell script would be good enough for that.

Comment: What does authorize mean in your case? Are you getting some kind of a token after you have authorized a user? Can you just pass this token to your application, instead of username/password, and that your application will work?

Answer (score 6):

When you `nohup java`, you're forcing the JVM *not* to use a console.  When you use the java `Console` object, you're attempting to interface a non-existent console and hence will always get a null `Console` reference.

i.e. it can't be done: it's a contradiction.

---

From **nohup** man page:

> *If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from /dev/null. If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if possible, '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise. If standard error is a terminal, redirect it to standard output. To save output to FILE, use 'nohup COMMAND > FILE'.*

i.e. it disconnects the process from interactive I/O (the unix/linux character-based console device) and connects to filesystem I/O.

From Java 7 javadoc for **Console**:

> *Methods to access the character-based console device, if any, associated with the current Java virtual machine.*
>
> *Whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the underlying platform and also upon the manner in which the virtual machine is invoked. If the virtual machine is started from an interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and output streams then its console will exist and will typically be connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine was launched. If the virtual machine is started automatically, for example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have a console.*
>
> *If this virtual machine has a console then it is represented by a unique instance of this class which can be obtained by invoking the System.console() method. If no console device is available then an invocation of that method will return null.*

---

**Alternative Solutions (Decreasing Order of Preference):**

1. **Don't use nohup; Run server as Unix/Linux daemon service**

   Daemon service can only be started/stopped via administrator (interactive) or administrative configuration (automated).  Then you wouldn't need to login as a "java server admin", but instead use the secure Unix/Linux login.  I would expect any client connecting to server would need to carry out application-layer authentication (possibly/probably independent of unix user accounts).

   See [Tool for creating a Java daemon service on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311268/tool-for-creating-a-java-daemon-service-on-linux) and

   http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html

   or your trusty Unix/Linux Administrator's Text Book
2. **Don't use java Console; Use java UI screen to Prompt**

   Prompt for username/password using one of: Swing / AWT / JavaFx.
   Use char[] to store the password (see http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/why-character-array-is-better-than.html  and   http://java.about.com/od/UsingDialogBoxes/a/How-To-Make-A-Password-Dialog-Box.htm and http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Java/Javas-Basic-User-Interface-Components/8/)
3. **Run command without nohup, within [Gnu Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session**

   Gnu screen continues to run programs, even when user closes terminal window.  The server screen session still exists in a detached mode.
4. **(Flawed) Set username/password as command-line args & system properties -DXXX**:

   Run a startup script as follows:

   ```
        <startupscriptname>.sh username password
   ```

   Inside `<startupscriptname>.sh`:

   ```
        #! /bin/sh
        nohup java MainClassName -Dadmin.username=$1 -Dadmin.password=$2 > myout.txt 2>&1 &
   ```

   In java:

   ```
        String adminUsername = System.getProperty("admin.username");
        // Avoid String for password, so it can't be snooped in the String values pool
        char[] adminPassword = System.getProperty("admin.password").toCharArray();
   ```

   **Problem:**  Tried to avoid using **`String`** for password.  But `System.getProperty` returns it as `String`, before it's converted to `char[]`.

   Also, have stronger security when user is prompted for password, rather than having password input as script command line argument.
5. **(Hacky) Run the server without nohup, but then manually "background nohup" it**

   Run the server as:

   ```
         java MainClassName
   ```

   Then enter username and password through `Console`.

   Then run one of:

   ```
         nohup -p <PID>
   ```

   or

   ```
         disown -h <JOB>
   ```

   **Problem:**  Can't script this altogether, if want interactive username/password in the middle.  Hence, there's a risk user may forget to do all steps, meaning app dies when user logs out (HUP signal).  Also, a problem for `disown`: `stdin, stdout & stderr` will be non-functional and won't be redirected: .

Comment: 1. my requirement is to start the server application based on username and password only. it is not OS's username/password. it is my own applications authentication scheme. so i am ruling out option-1.

Comment: X server will not be running in the server machines. So i am ruling out option-2

Comment: i am not sure about option-3. I will explore

Comment: i don't want to supply authentication credentials in terminal prompt. I am ruling out option-4

Comment: eventhough option-5 is a workaround, that seems to be a working solution to my problem. i will be preferring that option...

Comment: thanks for your time for the big reply. i will upvote it after 10 mins

Comment: You're welcome. :)  Option 1 is the preferred Unix/Linux way to run a service.  It has less requirements - no need for artificial app-level admin authentication & account management.  It starts the service when the server boots (if you want).  It supports smart admin via /sbin/service, /sbin/chkconfig, /sbin/  GUI /usr/bin/system-config-services, it integrates with monitoring and auto-restart tool monit. See http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/03/09/understanding-your-red-hat-enterprise-linux-daemons/ and http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-monitor-and-restart-linux-unix-service.html

Answer (score 2):

`nohup` is a simple way of daemonizing a process. Too simple for your needs.  `bash` is not able to daemonize a process except for using `nohup` or `disown`, neither of which suits your purpose.  Java tries very hard to stay away from OS-level details like daemonizing.

So what you need to do is write a small wrapper in another language that gets the username and password from the terminal, then daemonizes itself, then launches the Java program, passing username and password to it via a pipe.   (I'd use a key-value format and read from stdin in the Java program to make things easier, but you can do it other ways.) [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/) makes this easy in python, but you can do it in [C](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/c-daemon-process/) or [perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Server/lib/Net/Server/Daemonize.pm) or [Ruby](http://daemons.rubyforge.org).